# how would I send append data via json

Tags: javascript, php, json, append

Hi i currently have a document where i need to send data off via either email(which i am using php mailer) or sql. which is all pretty well sorted.

my only question is. as i am using append to generate a set of variables. how would i use pull all this user generated data to then send a json file.

below is the current code i have.

```
<div align="center" class="addsection"></div>
<button align="center" id="addbutton" class="btn btn-default">Add a product</button>
<button id="submitbutton" class="btn btn-default" onclick="sbmitbtn()">Submit</button>

<script>$('#addbutton').on('click', function () {
    var count = $('div.addsection div').length, id = count + 1;
    var large = '<p class="accordian_container">
                <hr/>
                    <p class="accordian_item" id="accord_item_2">
                        <label> First Name</label><br/>
                        <input type="text"/><br/>
                        <label>Middle Name</label><br/>
                        <input type="text"/><br/>
                        <label>Last Name</label><br/>
                        <input type="text" /><br/>
                        <label>Home Number</label><br/>
                        <input type="text"/><br>
                        <label>Work Number</label><br/>
                        <input type="text"/><br>
                        <label>Cell Number</label><br/>
                        <input type="text"/><br>
                    </p>
                </p>';

    $('div.addsection').append('<div class="contentprint" id="product' + id + '">' +
        '<h4>Product: ' + id + '</h4> <table class="selection1"></table>content goes here</div>');

    $('div.addsection').append(large);

    event.preventDefault();
});

$('#submitbutton').on('click', function () { 
}
```

as you can tell i have a button to generate content. with a div to put that content in. now i need to figure out how to use that data that was created from the textboxes to send off via json. is this possible. any help would be awesome. do i need to move large within the append and make each items id have the id of the overall div. and if so is it as simple as running a for loop until all divs with ids have been passed.

can this json type array be done in php if it were on a php page. its a little confusing to get my head around so any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Well, yes. I personally HATE jQuery so even though I do know how to use it, I always do this with the native JavaScript AJAX functions, still it's pretty easy to do if you ask me. But yes, you can definitely append it all, send it on and then process it with PHP using the `json_decode()` function. But there's  an interesting thing about this... there's no way you can do it as you've written it so far, you must add the `name` attributes to your inputs setting them as arrays. I'd usually use `id` attributes but since you need multiple fields for the same data, you'll need arrays.

Comment: I would actually post an answer but it's been so long since I last used jQuery that I'm sure I'll make lots of mistakes, I can do it with plain JavaScript though, if that helps/works.